# Nodejs app on heroku some files dont load status H10

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have created my startup's website! It took me 5 months. This is my fist Node.js web application. I finished 2 days ago and uploaded my project on Heroku. Happy beginning! 
But I have a big issue with the error that comes back every 3 or 4 page refreshes, the consol gives me status 503 "name.css or name.js" service unavailable and in my Heroku logs I see H10 error the same "Service unavailable". 
This happens with different files js, css, sometime images can't load, never the same files.
I'am on MacBook pro and uses atom. 
Can anybody tell me what's going on?

Here is my app.js

```js
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
var expressValidator = require('express-validator');
var session = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var mongorelation = require('mongo-relation');
var formidable = require('formidable');
var fs = require('fs');
var device = require('express-device');
var app = express();

mongoose.connect("**************");
var db = mongoose.connection;

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('.hbs', exphbs({
  defaultLayout:'layout',
  partialsDir: __dirname + '/views/utils/',
  extname: '.hbs',
    helpers: {
      last: function(array){return array[array.length -1].msg;},
      subject: function(str){if (str.length > 50) return str.substring(0,50) + '...'; return str; }
    }
  })
);

app.set('view engine', '.hbs');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(device.capture());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));

app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret',
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(expressValidator({
  errorFormatter: function(param, msg, value) {
      var namespace = param.split('.')
      , root    = namespace.shift()
      , formParam = root;

    while(namespace.length) {
      formParam += '[' + namespace.shift() + ']';
    }
    return {
      param : formParam,
      msg   : msg,
      value : value
    };
  }
}));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 3000));
app.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
 console.log('Server started on port '+app.get('port'));
});
```

And here is my package.json

```js
{
  "name": "compname",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "compdesc",
  "private": false,
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "authors",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "*",
    "body-parser": "*",
    "connect-timeout": "^1.8.0",
    "cookie-parser": "*",
    "dotenv": "^4.0.0",
    "express": "*",
    "express-device": "^0.4.2",
    "express-handlebars": "*",
    "express-handlebars-paginate": "^1.0.3",
    "express-messages": "*",
    "express-session": "*",
    "express-validator": "*",
    "formidable": "^1.0.17",
    "handlebars-helper-eachitems": "^0.1.2",
    "handlebars-helper-paginate": "^0.2.0",
    "handlebars-paginate": "^0.1.0",
    "http": "0.0.0",
    "https": "^1.0.0",
    "image-size": "^0.5.0",
    "imagesloaded": "^4.1.1",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "masonry-layout": "^4.1.1",
    "moment": "^2.17.1",
    "mongo-relation": "^0.5.4",
    "mongodb": "*",
    "mongoose": "*",
    "mongoose-aggregate-paginate": "^1.0.5",
    "mongoose-relationship": "^0.1.5",
    "multer": "^1.2.0",
    "multer-storage-s3": "^1.1.1",
    "node-uuid": "^1.4.7",
    "nodemailer": "~0.7.1",
    "passport": "*",
    "passport-http": "*",
    "passport-local": "*",
    "promise": "^7.1.1",
    "pusher": "^1.5.1",
    "random-js": "^1.0.8",
    "s3fs": "^2.5.0",
    "socket.io": "^1.7.2",
    "twilio": "^2.11.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "handlebars-helper-paginate": "^0.2.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Heroku is currently having issues, read more here: https://status.heroku.com/incidents/1091
More info about the H10 app crashed error:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h10-app-crashed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long day of suffering, I finally got it to work. I updated my versions of node 6.9.1 to 7.8.0 and npm from 3.0... to 4.4.4 and i spécified it in the package.json.

```js
{
  "name": "Fason",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Company Name",
  "private": false,
  "main": "app.js",
  "author": "Me",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "passport-local": "*",
    "promise": "^7.1.1",
    "pusher": "^1.5.1",
    "random-js": "^1.0.8",
    "s3fs": "^2.5.0",
    "socket.io": "^1.7.2",
    "twilio": "^2.11.1"
  },
  "engines": {
        "node": "7.8.0",
        "npm": "4.4.4"
    }
}
```

like that. 
Hope that this will help someone.